# karate-config.js not indentifying karate keyword

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I am creating a karate automation framework and have a karate-config.js file in the framework. When I try to declare anything using `var` or try to use the `karate` keyword it is showing me warnings:

> 'var' is used instead of 'let' or 'const' unresolved variable of type
> karate.

Because of this I am not able to use env variables. How do I resolve this?

I am expecting the keywords to be identified by the framework. Am I missing some plugin or dependency in the IDE? The same project when I share it with my teammates is working fine in their systems.[karate-config ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbld7.png)

Comment: without you sharing your karate-config.js, no one can help identify the issue.

If you don't want to do that, please re-read the doc for [karate-config](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate) this specifically has an example for different envs

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the karate-config file. pls check and see if any issue can be found

Answer (score 0):

You need the plugin for whichever IDE you are using - [documentation link](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/IDE-Support)

This is assuming that your pom matches the [documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#maven).

I disabled the plugin and I now see the same "unresolved variable or type karate" error, but **my test still runs** because I have set up the environment variables

This will not fix the fact that you haven't set up an env URL for 'qa' / anything else. You have only set

```
var env = karate.env
if (!env) {
   env = 'qa';
}
```

the documentation has an [example](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#configuration) - please refer to it